# Return the list of users in prolog

Tags: prolog

My goal is return the  list of X users with T tags in common with a specific user and one of them is mandatory.

I have this Knowledge Base:

```
%node(Id, Name, ListOfTags)
node(1,ana,[nature,cat,dog,sw,csharp]).
node(11,antonio,[cat,nature,car,sport,city]).
node(22,isabel,[nature,cat,test,dog,c]).
node(23,john,[nature,dog,sw,csharp,city]).
node(24,maria,[nature,e,b,c,d]).
```

based on this predicate:

```
suggest_group(Name, NumberOfUsers, MandatoryTag, ListOfGroup)
```

when the question `?- suggest_group(ana, 3, cat, LGroup)` is asked the result must be `LGroup = []` because there is no group of 3 users with the mandatory tag cat with ana.

If i make the question `suggest_group(ana, 2, cat, LGroup)` the result must be `LGroup = [antonio, isabel]` because they have the mandatory tag cat in common with ana.

I have this:

```
users_x_common_tags(CurrentUser,NumberOfTags, NumberOfUsers, MandatoryTag, List_Result):-
    node(_,CurrentUser,Tags),
    findall(User,(node(_,User,_),User \== CurrentUser),Users),
    users_x_common_tags2(NumberOfTags, NumberOfUsers, MandatoryTag, Tags,Users,List_Result).

users_x_common_tags2(_,_,_,_,[],[]):-!.
users_x_common_tags2(X,N,M,Tags,[U|Users],Result):-
    node(_,U,User_Tags),
    intersection(Tags, User_Tags,Commun),
    member(M,Commun),
    length(Commun, Size),
    Size >= X, !,
    users_x_common_tags2(X,N,M,Tags,Users,Result1),
    append([U], Result1, Result).
    
users_x_common_tags2(X,N,M,Tags,[_|Users],Result):-
    !,
    users_x_common_tags2(X,N,M,Tags,Users,Result).
```

How can i return the list if the length its NumberOfUsers otherwise return an empty List?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241322/discussion-on-question-by-flavio-jardim-return-the-list-of-users-in-prolog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest code I've written, but I think it works:

```
node(1,ana,[nature,cat,dog,sw,csharp]).
node(11,antonio,[cat,nature,car,sport,city]).
node(22,isabel,[nature,test,dog,cat]).
node(23,john,[nature,dog,sw,csharp,city]).
node(24,maria,[nature,e,b,c,d]).

suggest_group(Name, NumberOfUsers, MandatoryTag, ListOfGroup) :-
    findall((X,Xs),(node(_,X,Xs),X \== Name,member(MandatoryTag,Xs)),Zs),
    (collapse(Zs,(ListOfGroup,_)),length(ListOfGroup,NumberOfUsers);ListOfGroup=[]).

collapse([(U,Ts)],([U],Ts)).
collapse([(U,Ts)|Rs],([U|Us],Xs)) :-
    collapse(Rs,(Us,Ws)),
    intersection(Ts,Ws,Xs).
```

```
?- suggest_group(ana, 3, cat, LGroup).
LGroup = [].

?- suggest_group(ana, 2, cat, LGroup).
LGroup = [antonio, isabel] .
```

Comment: @FlávioJardim - I'm glad you improved your question.